# How to create different roles in SELINUX?

Tags: selinux

I'm working on access control lab in my school and I'm stuck at using SELINUX.

I'm supposed to create two roles: user and admin.

I have SELINUX installed on UBUNTU using `sudo apt-get install selinux`.

When I type `getenforce`, it says `permissive`.

Should I just create two roles using `useradd`? and how do I change to admin context (let's say I have admin user) ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a CLI utility that can create roles, I suppose that the roles in the refpolicy are enough for most use cases. This said, I would recommend referring to the [docs](http://selinuxproject.org/page/RefpolicyBasicRoleCreation#Creating_the_Policy_for_the_New_Role), you will need to create a simple policy source file. A good starting point for creating such file is [this](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials/Creating_your_own_policy_module_file).

The permissive mode means that selinux is logging access violations but not blocking them, depending on your lab setup you will be probably required to switch to one of enforcing, mcs or mls but that's a different story but this should have no effect on the way you create roles.

If in doubt about selinux stuff you may find more info in the main documentation of the selinux project, in the gentoo-hardened docs and also in [this guide](https://www.berrange.com/~dan/selinux-policy.txt).

Hope this helps.